# running cursor in parallel

Tags: sql, cursor

I’m trying to find a way to run the cursor in parallel. Cause the rows are isolated and nothing to do with each other, to make it more efficient and faster.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything like Parallel CURSOR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693474/is-there-anything-like-parallel-cursor)

Comment: I'm looking for kinda automated way doing parallel cursors...