# How can I get a parallel stream from a database procedure?

Tags: oracle, kotlin, stream, parallel.foreach

I am trying to process a stream from the database in parallel, but I only get it to work if I change the line

```
.parallel().forEach
```

into any of

```
.distinct().parallel().forEach
.limit(1_000_000).parallel().forEach
.sort(MyComparator).parallel().forEach
```

which all result in evaluating the entire stream first before starting to process. So my question is: is there anything I can do get it to work instantly without any intermediate operation (like distinct/sort/limit)?

The kotlin code (simplified) looks like

```
  fun handleItems() {
      try {
          repo.findItems().use { items ->
              items.parallel().forEach {
                  doThings(it)
              }
          }
      } finally {
            // 
      }
  }
```

The 'repo.findItems()' calls a db procedure that returns: `Stream<Item>`; the oracle procedure (simplified) looks like

```
  function get_items
    ( p_start_date in item_table.date_start%type default null
    , p_end_date   in item_table.date_end%type   default null
    )
  return package_item.cursor_type
  is
    --
    -- Local variables ...
    l_sysdate     date := trunc( sysdate );
    l_ref_cursor  cursor_type;
    --
  begin
    --
    open l_ref_cursor
    for
    select itemz.id
    ,      itemz.code
    ,      [more fields] 
    from   item_table         itemz
    join   item_table_detail  itemd on  itemz.id  = itemd.itemz_id
    where  [where clause]
    union  all
    select itemz.id
    ,      itemz.code,
    ,      [more fields]  
    from   item_table         itemz
    join   item_table_detail  itemd on  itemz.id  = itemd.itemz_id
    where  [where clause]
    ;
    --
    return l_ref_cursor;
    --
  end get_items
  ;
```

Comment: Looks like this is an intentional limitation of that `Stream` implementation, cause cursor is sequentional by its nature. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693474/is-there-anything-like-parallel-cursor

Comment: Mm, I guess that "cursor is sequentional by its nature" answers the question..